# Custom view as a tabbar, pushViewController not working

Tags: iphone, xcode

Using custom view as a tab bar, it is declared in delegate so that it ca be available on all views. But the issue is the pushViewController is not implementing there. I am using the custom view to get the navigation controller animation on bottom bar because this can not be implemented on tab bar. So, how can i perform pushViewController to the bar buttons.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.homeViewController = [[[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.homeViewController];

navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

[self.window addSubview:self.navController.view];

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;   [appDelegate addCustomBottomBar];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}

-(void)addCustomBottomBar{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.window cache:YES];

viewBotBar = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 402, 320, 79)];
viewBotBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1aa.png"]];
[self.window addSubview:viewBotBar];
[self.window bringSubviewToFront:viewBotBar];

[UIView commitAnimations];

UIButton *btnHome = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnHome.frame = CGRectMake(0, 25, 54, 50);
[btnHome setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnHome addTarget:self action:@selector(home) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[viewBotBar addSubview:btnHome];

UIButton *btnLoc = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnLoc.frame = CGRectMake(58, 25, 63, 50);
[btnLoc setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnLoc addTarget:self action:@selector(loc) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[viewBotBar addSubview:btnLoc];

UIButton *btnSer = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnSer.frame = CGRectMake(124, 25, 63, 50);
[btnSer setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnSer addTarget:self action:@selector(ser) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[viewBotBar addSubview:btnSer];

UIButton *btnBook = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnBook.frame = CGRectMake(190, 25, 63, 50);
[btnBook setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnBook addTarget:self action:@selector(book) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[viewBotBar addSubview:btnBook];

UIButton *btnMore = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnMore.frame = CGRectMake(256, 25, 62, 50);
[btnMore setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnMore addTarget:self action:@selector(more) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[viewBotBar addSubview:btnMore];


btnDwn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnDwn.frame = CGRectMake(135, 0, 45, 28);
[btnDwn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnDwn addTarget:self action:@selector(down) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btnDwn.tag = 1;
[viewBotBar addSubview:btnDwn];
}

-(void)down
{
if (btnDwn.tag == 1) {
    // perform your required functionality
    btnDwn.tag = 2;

    CGRect newFrameSize = CGRectMake(0, 452, 320, 28);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0];
    viewBotBar.frame = newFrameSize;
    viewBotBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom-hidden.png"]];
   // self.tabController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
else if (btnDwn.tag == 2) {
    // perform your required functionality
    btnDwn.tag = 1;

    CGRect newFrameSize = CGRectMake(0, 402, 320, 79);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0];

    viewBotBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1aa.png"]];
    viewBotBar.frame = newFrameSize;
     //self.tabController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
}

-(void)loc
{
LocationViewController *location = [[LocationViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:location animated:YES];
}

-(void)ser
{
ServicesViewController *services = [[ServicesViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ServicesViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:services animated:YES];
}

-(void)book
{
BookingViewController *book = [[BookingViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"BookingViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:book animated:YES];
}

-(void)more
{
MoreViewController *more = [[MoreViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MoreViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:more animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: put your code please.. :)

Comment: Share some code first...

Comment: post the code of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of AppDelegate.m file

Answer (score 1):

use

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
```

instead of

```
[self.window addSubview:self.navController.view];
```

see these custom `UITabBar` Demos Links..

1. [Many Demos](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tabbar)
2. [PeekabooTabBarController](https://github.com/a1phanumeric/PeekabooTabBarController)

Comment: It doesn't accept pushViewController, still it gives error.

Comment: wait i find my answer otherwise i post the code that how to use custom tabbar ok...

Comment: @AppleDatasource first see this link of my blog that how we set the tabbar to the window and how to set class to that dude see http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-set-tabbar-with-viewcontroller.html

Comment: Bro i know how to set tab bar controller with navigation controller, problem is with custom bar, please show how to have custom view as bottom bar and showable on all views, with buttons on it working on pushViewController.

Comment: yes yes i know bro just wait dude i make this type of one application i which i displayed the different types of image on every button of tabbar but here many code for that so i thought what i do some links for custom tabbar or mine...

Comment: @AppleDatasource hey follow this link dude.. https://github.com/a1phanumeric/PeekabooTabBarController

Comment: @AppleDatasource http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tabbar see this link with maannnyyy demos for customtabbar .. :)

Comment: I already seen this please look at question again, it said that animation required of pushViewController.

Comment: I have seen that, after all this i put question, there is no such example in which tab bar buttons work on pushViewController. I mean to say when tab button is clicked it works like [self.navigatioController pushViewController:] works.

Comment: I have two requirements bottom bar on all views and works on pushViewController. Tab bar fulfills first requirement and custom view fits second, i am looking for one solution consists of both.

Comment: but dude here your code not work properly bcoz here you not use the view as a UITabbar , it must be work as a UITabbar bcoz here we identify the index number of viewController like if user click 1 button then we put this example see - (void) loadBookContent :(int)index { 
        [[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index] viewWillAppear:YES];
    }